# Python Заполнение json структуры данных на основе данных из другого JSON

Tags: python, json, list, dict

Всем привет, не жду решения, но не могу понять в какую сторону копать.

На выходе необходимо получить JSON файл с заполненными ключами "value". По работе с JSON вопросов нет, получаем словарь json файла и дальше его преобразуем, не совсем понимаю как его заполнить, т.к в самом словаре вложены списки со словарями, в которых так же вложены списки со словарями, в общем матрешка, выглядит следующим образом:

```
{'tests': [{'id': 2, 'title': 'Smoke test', 'value': ''}, {'id': 41, 'title': 'Debug test', 'value': ''}, {'id': 73, 'title': 'Performance test', 'value': '', 'values': [{'id': 345, 'title': 'Maxperf', 'value': '', 'values': [{'id': 230, 'title': 'Percent', 'values': [{'id': 234, 'title': '200', 'value': ''}, {'id': 653, 'title': '300', 'value': ''}]}]}, {'id': 110, 'title': 'Stability test', 'value': '', 'values': [{'id': 261, 'title': 'Percent', 'values': [{'id': 238, 'title': '160', 'value': ''}, {'id': 690, 'title': '240', 'value': ''}]}]}]}, {'id': 122, 'title': 'Security test', 'value': '', 'values': [{'id': 5321, 'title': 'Confidentiality', 'value': ''}, {'id': 5322, 'title': 'Integrity', 'value': ''}]}]
```

второй json с результатами тестов:

```
{'values': [{'id': 2, 'value': 'passed'}, {'id': 41, 'value': 'passed'}, {'id': 73, 'value': 'passed'}, {'id': 110, 'value': 'failed'}, {'id': 122, 'value': 'failed'}, {'id': 234, 'value': 'passed'}, {'id': 238, 'value': 'passed'}, {'id': 345, 'value': 'passed'}, {'id': 653, 'value': 'passed'}, {'id': 690, 'value': 'failed'}, {'id': 5321, 'value': 'passed'}, {'id': 5322, 'value': 'failed'}]}
```

На сколько я себе представляю алгоритм, нам необходимо взять значение ключа id из rsults.json, найти его в test.json и присвоить ключу "value" значение из results.

Хочу разобраться, как такое можно реализовать. Гугл, что то внятных ответов как это можно сделать не дает, возможно ищу не правильно.

Comment: Для начала надо точно сформулировать задачу, описать что есть на входе (ну это более менее понятно, вы привели примеры). И так же точно описать как это должно выглядеть на выходе. Так же не забыть указать является ли например поле id уникальным, не зависимо от уровня вложенности. И если вдруг одновременно две записи с id=10 могут быть в одном файле, вложенными в разные записи (например с id=8 и id=12), то решать как же уникально идентифицировать значения

Comment: А вообще если есть что то вложенное неограниченное количество раз, то скорее всего надо использовать рекурсию

Comment: id уникальные, но мне не совсем понятно, как проходится по этому словарю и находить значение id в нем. Т.е Если бы это был просто обычный словарь, тогда можно было использовать метод .get('id') и получать данные всех id. Но т.к тут вложены списки несколько раз, мне не совсем понятно как это делать.

Comment: Повторю, ключевое слово "_рекурсия_". Т.е. функция, которая обрабатывает переданные данные и если вдруг очередное значение содержит values и это массив, то вызывать саму себя с передачей параметром уже этого массива